# Unhandled exception in listener callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pynput

I was working on a screenshot tool and I tried to create a loop that will create variables named e1,e2,e3, and e4 upon every click but I didnt knew that this loop will restart itself 4 times upon just one click:

```
def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    e4 = None
    while e4 == None:
        z=1 
        print("Assigned the edge where located at {0} {1} !".format(x,y))
        exec("e + {0}= ({1},{2})".format(z,x,y))
        z += 1
```

and then I have defined the required on_move and on_scroll functions:

```
def on_move(x,y):
    pass


def on_scroll(x,y,dx,dy):
    pass
```

then I used the code that everyone using pynput uses:

```
with Listener(on_move=on_move,on_click=on_click,on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

and after these, I tested the code and I got these errors:

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 380, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 395, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 384, in _handler
    self._handle(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 191, in _handle
    self.on_click(data.pt.x, data.pt.y, button, pressed)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\sstool.py", line 13, in on_click
    exec("e + {0}= ({1},{2})".format(z,x,y))
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 380, in _handler
    converted = self._convert(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 395, in _convert
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\sstool.py", line 25, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 210, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "c:\users\admin\desktop\pynput-1.6.8\.eggs\six-1.15.0-py3.8.egg\six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 162, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\win32.py", line 384, in _handler
    self._handle(code, msg, lpdata)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\mouse\_win32.py", line 191, in _handle
    self.on_click(data.pt.x, data.pt.y, button, pressed)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.6.8-py3.8.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 78, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\sstool.py", line 13, in on_click
    exec("e + {0}= ({1},{2})".format(z,x,y))
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

How can I assign these variables one by one upon click and what is the reasons of another errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the right solution here is but the main error is happening because of this statement `exec("e + {0}= ({1},{2})".format(z,x,y))`.

You can use an example to see the same behavior e.g. exec("e+1=(1,1)") will raise the same issue.

The solution there is to simply remove the `+` i.e. `exec("e{0}=({1}, {2})")` - which will do what you expect and create e1, e2, e3 and e4.